# ROS Answers SE migration: RVIz crashes

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, when I tray to run rviz it crashes and give this message:

```
[ERROR] [1317805053.151646864]: Caught exception while loading: Tried to subscribe to a topic with the same name but different md5sum as a topic that was already subscribed [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo/c9a58c1b0b154e0e6da7578cb991d214 vs. sensor_msgs/Image/060021388200f6f0f447d0fcd9c64743]
```

I have looked for it all around internet but found nothing.

Can somebody help me?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11414/rviz-crashes/) by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2011-10-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Usually, MD5 message signature mismatches are due to incompatible message versions, often from mixing code from multiple releases.

In this case, it appears that you are somehow confusing the topic names for `sensor_msgs/CameraInfo` and `sensor_msgs/Image`. Those are two different messages that are typically published simultaneously on separate topic names by camera drivers. Their topic names usually end in `camera/camera_info` and `camera/image_raw` (respectively).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4